# Запятая после "но"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "но"?

> Но(,) как оказалось, чьи-либо указания ему были не нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если противопоставление относится к основной фразе (после вводного сочетания), как, скорее всего, и есть, то запятая нужна. Таким образом, получается, что при изъятии вводного выражения фраза не теряет своего смысла. В тех же случаях, когда смысл теряется, союз присоединяют к вводному сочетанию и ставят одну запятую после него.